# Search engine to tell where a certain font is being used commercially

Tags: fonts, resource-recommendations

**Is there a search engine that tells where a certain font is being used commercially?** For example which company is using it in their logo, etc.

A specific example is that I would like to know where the font "[Danube Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/search/danube+pro/fonts/)" is being used already (by which companies in their products or logos).

*Note/Update:*

I don't mean *everywhere* (in the sense of legally secure) but those logos that are online on the web. I think from a technical perspective it could be done with certain algorithms to crawl websites and use some algorithms to create a database of such. Just like Google crawls for text/content and also since there exists font identification platforms, same could be done for what I described above. My question is therefore if it has been done. Or similar to **reverse image searches**, such as http://www.plaghunter.com/en/, where you can search where on the web an image is being used just based on the motive.

There is a **brand database** that does show images/logos at http://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/, but it does not allow you to search for **font names**.

[image]

Even audio logo databases exist, http://audio-logo-database.com/, now I am just looking for the same specialized on fonts.

Comment: Why is this question being down-voted without any comment? It's a valid question regarding corporate design and font usage and relevant for graphic designers (also for legal questions).

Comment: This is quite a big request - to categorize when businesses use which font in *every product, and logo*. I don't believe there is such a resource

Comment: I don't mean *every* (in the sense of legally secure) but those that are online. I think from a technical perspective it could be done with certain algorithms to crawl websites and use some algorithms to create a database of such. Just like Google crawls for text/content and also since there exists font identification platforms, same could be done for what I described above. My question is therefore if it has been done. Or similar to reverse image searches, such as http://www.plaghunter.com/en/, where you can search where on the web an image is being used just based on the motive.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I updated my post: think such databases exist that holds a number of company name and products (logos), at least the registered ones, such as the brand database WIPO - the problem is just that it does not let you search by the used font name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not exhaustive, [fontsinuse.com](http://fontsinuse.com) has good examples of use of any given font.

Answer (score 0):

Not every business has their logos/etc online, that is also a problem to your request... But might google image search do some good? It can already search images based on other images, I suppose searching for bits of said fonts could wield some results, 'though I bet not satisfactory enough...

Answer (score 0):

It could be done for logos that are using fonts (aren't a flat image), which is a small portion, but for images it would take a lot of processing power to do it; too much for a free or cheap service.

Based on this not being a common request, I doubt it exists.